# How do I print a certain wordpress category anywhere I want on any page?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

Can someone tell me what the PHP would look like in order to get a category from Wordpress and then print it where ever I want?

I'm guessing I have to build a PHP function.  Something like:

function get_a_category() {

$category = get_the_category(); <-----( not sure how to ge ta specific category )

echo $category;

}

I have no idea I know nothing about PHP

can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write your own function; you do have to work with the [The Loop (WordPress Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and a new query [(Function Reference/query posts « WordPress Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) to keep the original WP loop in place. Run this new query in a page template to get the first post from "mycategory". Change showposts to the number of posts you want.

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=mycategory&showposts=1'); ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function get_a_category() {
    $category = get_the_category();
    foreach ($category AS $key => $value) {
        $category_name[] = $value->cat_name;
    }
    $categories = implode(', ',$category_name);
    echo $categories;
}
```